# Remove unnecessary logs in cli

Tags: nativescript

How to remove this unnecessary logs in my command line. Because it's really hard to see my own logged datas. It appears when I updated my nativescript version to `4.0.0+`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any examples of the kinds of unnecessary logs you're seeing? iOS or Android?

If you're on iOS, one possible case is that you're seeing a bunch of extra logs related to network requests. As of 4.1.0, there still appears to be a problem that causes these logs to reach the console when a network request fails. This is a bug. These logs should NOT reach the console unless you run `tns device log`.

If this is the problem you're encountering, you can track the issue (and resolution) here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3544

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently developing on IOS and I'm seeing a bunch of extra logs not related to my work.